# Reference as member variable

Tags: c++, reference, member

Can someone explain me why it isn’t possible for the class TaxWay in the code to hold a member variable Bank that is initialized by a reference? What should I change in the code to make it correct? 
When I change the member variable to a reference as `Bank&`, then it works. I thought that the same should happen with a “not reference variable”. How can it be done?

```
class Bank;

class TaxWay : public Way
{
  public:
    TaxSquare(int, int, Bank&);
    virtual void process();

  private:
    int taxAmount;
    Bank bank;
};

TaxWay::TaxWay(int anID, int amount, Bank& theBank) 
: Way(anID),taxAmount(amount),bank(theBank) 
{
}
```

I create an object as:

```
TaxWay TaxWay9(9,150, theBank);
```

Comment: What error do you get from the compiler? Can you show the *actual* code that causes this error?

Comment: I tried to compile this, but after fixing three error messages, I gave up. You'll have to do better than this if you want us to help you!

Comment: It is just a segment of code, not the whole one. I thought it was enough to express my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the example the `TaxWay` class cannot hold a copy of the bank, because you have not defined the `Bank` class. At a minimum the size of the `Bank` class must be known so space can be allocated.

On the other hand, depending on what the `Bank` contains, it might not be a good idea to copy it. Will that also copy the money in the bank? :-)

Comment: If I got it, you suggest using a reference as member variable. That is what I intended to do. The taxWay needs to modify the money of the bank as well. I had merely the question why not compiling other way. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 6):

Two important points:

- If you want to declare the member variable as `Bank bank`, then you have to include the header file which has the definition of class `Bank`. Just forward declaration, as you have done, would result in compilation error.
- However, if you want to declare it as `Bank & bank` OR `Bank *bank`, then forward declaration is enough. The definition of class `Bank` is not needed in this case, unless you want to access any member of `Bank` (for example, in inline definition of some member functions of the class `TaxWay`).

Answer (score 3):

One thing (that may or may not be your problem) is that you've declared `Bank` as a forward declaration with no definition. When the compiler reaches `TaxWay`, you won't be able to declare a member variable of type `Bank` because the compiler doesn't know anything about the class `Bank` yet.